# jQuery some easings not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I'm using the following code to animate my navbar:

```
$(".sidenav").animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 800, 'easeOutElastic', function() {});
```

Unfortunatelly, easeOutElastic doesn't seem to work. The error console shows the following log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutElastic'
```

Same with some other easings like 'easeOutExpo'

However, `linear` works.

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI? http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Comment: No, I don't. Now I do - thanks, working! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Linear easing is built into jQuery, but you need to include jQuery UI to get the more advanced easing effects.  http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned you must use jQuery UI. You can also use [this](http://jaukia.github.io/easie/) plugin